# Analysing high degree polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

What are the tools to analyse high degree polynomial ? I mean how can we sketch the graph of these functions and prove properties about it. Most of my knowledge failed to answer my question ‘cause I need to find roots of high degree polynomial.

I know that we can’t explicitly find the roots and extremum but can we get properties of these quantities without explicitly finding them. For instance, let $x_1, \dots, x_r$ be the real roots of $f$ a polynomial, we proved that between $x_3$ and $x_4$ $f$ is positive, we proved that $x_2 \le B$ for $B \in \mathbf{R}$ a bound, and so on

In this example, I could plot the graph and I would get my answer but this is just an observation not a proof. Moreover, let says that we have family of high degree polynomial $f_{a}$, where $a$ is a real parameter, it looks, numerically, for all $a \ge 40$, the smallest root $x_a$ of $f_a$ verify $x_a \le \varphi(a)$, where $\varphi(a)$ is a formula in $a$. In this situation, I notice a behaviour but I need a proof to be sure that the conjecture is true even if I tested for all $a$ up to $10^{50}$.

Thank in advance :D

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  Finding the roots of general high degree polynomials can be very hard.  A standard sort of, somewhat discouraging, example is to let $p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{20} (x-i) +.001\times x^{19}$.  Note that this is very near a polynomial which is easily factored, but $p(x)$ has [fairly random looking roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+product%5B%28x-i%29%2C+%7Bi%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2B.001*x%5E19%3D0) including quite a few complex roots.

Comment: We can find reasonable bounds for real roots , but in general analyzing a polynomial is extremely hard since it can heavily oscillate and determining the roots can be numerically unstable. This is the reason why splines instead of very high degree interpolation polynomials are used to approximate a complicated function.

Comment: There are no general tool. Various tool are corresponding to various problems. Can you give example of problem, that you need to solve using this tool? One of possible tool is using derivatives or integrals. Let $p(x)$ is polynomial, then $g(x)=p'(x)$ is also polynomial. If you can show that $g(x)$ is always positive or always negative, then $p(x)=0$ has exactly one real root. Number of real roots of $p(x)$ is at most 1 + number of real roots of $g(x)=0$. There is at least one real root of $g(x)=0$ between two real roots of $p(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks @IvanKaznacheyeu. Actually even the positivity of a polynomial defeats me... For instance, the polynomial in the next comment looks positive between 0 and 50 but how to prove it ?

Comment: $-k^{22} - 171k^{21} - 12205k^{20} - 386865k^{19} + 4120220k^{18} + 1044300438k^{17} + 57596900718k^{16} + 2021077105470k^{15} + 52401701064135k^{14} + 1062401195233745k^{13} + 17327066684082250*k^{12} + 230921056708603060k^{11} + 2535579533311803000k^{10} + 22993407834358720000k^9 + 171602215375615200000k^8 + 1043514778020066000000k^7 + 5084856251424312000000k^6 + 19410186930964500000000k^5 + 56485065655667000000000k^4 + 121104193409760000000000k^3 + 178708855500890000000000k^2 + 142655835305500000000000k$